# CHILD_PROCESS , DGRAM , DEFAULTABLE.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

can you help me please with this errors : 
I want to connect to a locally ip by ssh and i cant because i don't have the libraries , i tried to download them but they're empty .

> WARNING in ./node_modules/defaultable/defaultable.js
>
> 49:13-31 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/simple-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib/agent.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   '/home/mehdi/Escritorio/Login2/node_modules/simple-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/lookup.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in
>   '/home/mehdi/Escritorio/Login2/node_modules/native-dns-cache'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in
>   '/home/mehdi/Escritorio/Login2/node_modules/native-dns/lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/utils.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in
>   '/home/mehdi/Escritorio/Login2/node_modules/native-dns/lib'

Thank you very Much.

Comment: You should post you code too, what do you do with your code that produce this error? Also try remove `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, consider reading the following - it will help you getting an answer faster and also the person trying to help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask